# Prove 2+3(x-2)=5x-10 is incorrect

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My homework from the chapter of Order of Operations wants me to prove that the listed equations are incorrect. I am having a bit of a difficult time with this one, as the equation is correct when X=3. Am I going crazy, or is my teacher?

Comment: I think they mean incorrect in general, i.e. "not valid for all $x$." Find an $x$ that doesn't work.

Comment: Is it an equation or an identity for all $x$?

Comment: If this is really related to linear algebra, then are you sure you are including the *entire* problem statement? That is, one solution is different from the solution set...

Comment: Please confirm, is the question: Show that the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},~2+3(x-2)=5x-10$ is false?

Comment: @M10687 The question just states, "Prove the following equation is incorrect."

Comment: There is a difference between an identity such as $3x+4x=7x$ which is true for all possible values of the variable and an equation which is true for only one or a finite many values of the variable, such as $2x+1=9$ which is not true for all values of $x$ but only for $x=4$. Your teacher wants you to show that the equation is not an identity which you can do by showing that there is at least one value of $x$ for which it is NOT true.

Comment: @OlivierOloa It doesn't really specify, as I stated in the comment above, the question is vague and just states prove the equation is incorrect. So i assume, equation.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. So it's difficult to answer correctly ;)

Comment: Are some of the equations in the exercise identities, true for any value of the variable? If so it sounds as though the instructions are poorly worded and they want you to decide which equations are identities and which are not.

Comment: It needs to be true for all $x$ in the world not only the most recent or number 3 or anything. But I agree you should be careful with $x$s, can probably drive people crazy.

Comment: The problem statement could include a typo. What would happen if the given "equation" was $2x+3(x-2)=5x-10$ instead?

Comment: This problem is just screaming for the counter-example at $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is from a chapter about order of operations, they probably want you to show that in general (for an arbritrary $x$), the LHS (left hand side) is not equal to the RHS. That is, they want you to give a reason as to why subtracting $2$ from an arbritrary quantity $x$, multiplying the result by $3$, and adding $2$ to the total is not the same as just multiplying that same $x$ by $5$ and subtracting $10$.

There are various ways to show this. The easiest is to just find a counterexample. Try plugging in $0$ for $x$ (or any number other than $3$) on both sides an you will get a contradiction. This is sufficient to prove that this is not an (what we call) identity.

Another way to approach it is to solve for $x$. If this is really an identity, when we solve for $x$we should get something that suggests that the equation is true for all $x$,such as $x=x$. As you pointed out, when we solve for x we just get $x=3$, which means that there is just one unique solution, which in turn means that the equation is not true for arbitrary $x$.